# Python, tifffile tiff saved my stack image as multiple channel

Tags: python, imagej

I try to saved an image stack with tifffile.imwrite in python. But when I open my image in imageJ I have 100 channels instead of 100 plans.

I save my image in this way :

```
tifffile.imwrite('my_image.tif',
                 image.astype('float32'),
                 shape=image.shape,
                 imagej=True,
                 resolution=(1/X_SIZE, 1/Y_SIZE),
                 metadata={'spacing': Z_SIZE,
                           'unit': 'um',
                           'axes': 'ZXY',
                           })
```

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Looks like you are using an outdated version of tifffile that does not use the axes argument. Try updating tifffile and use `'axes': 'ZYX'`.

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed a problem of version. I thought I was the latest version of tifffile when I install it with conda, but it install the 2020..3 version.